# I can't create bootable USB drive with Startup Disk Creator

Tags: 11.04, usb, startup

After re-installation of Natty, I had lost ability to create bootable USB drive with Startup Disk Creator.

When I tried to add an `.iso` image into (through the button <kbd>Other</kbd>), nothing happend.

Disk Creator won't add the source CD image.

[image: Startup Disk Creator Image]

I have tried to re-install Startup Disk Creator, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Use Unetbootin.

Comment: Try launching the USB Creator from the Terminal - the command is 'usb-creator-gtk' - that might provide some useful output.

Comment: after launching from Terminal I've got the following output : isoinfo: Unable to find Joliet SVD

Comment: Still an [open bug on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/768791)

Answer (score 2):

I have read that a 2GB flash drive is now minimum for a Live install.
I have not confirmed this.

Alternatly you can boot the 712 MB Ubuntu iso image using grub2.
MultiBootUSB has script for doing this.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Min 2GB flash drive is not the issue; I am using 8GB flash drive